# WordPress - images and javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am very new to WordPress. I have converted a HTML website I created ([www.reactmarketing.co.uk/servowatch](http://www.reactmarketing.co.uk/servowatch)) into WordPress. On my dashboard it says that the theme is installed but none of the images are showing up and the JavaScript is not working.

My folder layout is:`wp-content/themese/servowatch`
inside the servowatch folder is:

```
footer.php
header.php
images (dir)
index.php
js (dir)
sidebar.php
style.css
```

the inside of my < head > looks like this. (copied from a tutorial i found)

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
```

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's path problem :) Change from `src="js/...` to `src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/...` and it will work. In CSS, make sure you point your images like this: `url('images/image.jpg');`.

Comment: so I think the JavaScript is now working, thank you. But I still cant display any images. In the CSS, image looks like this: .logo{
 background:url('/images/logo.png') no-repeat;} in the HTML images look like this: <img src="images/image01.jpg" alt="image description" width="1269" height="441" />

Comment: In CSS, don't use `/images/`, only `images/`. In html, use mentioned before `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/...`.

Answer (score 0):

add template directory path to your java script src or images src

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/

<script type="text/javascript" src="`<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/`js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="`<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/`js/jquery.main.js"></script>
```